# A concrete category has only forgetful functors?

Tags: category-theory

I am confused about definition. If category $C$ is small and $F$ faithful functor such that $F:C\rightarrow SET$ where $F$ doesn't change the structure of $C$ then the pair $(C,F)$ is concrete category?

Comment: What do you mean by "$F$ doesn't change the structure of $C$" ?

Comment: The title appears to claim that the only functor on a concrete category is a forgetful functor.  This is not a true statement.  The body says you are "confused about definition", but you do not clearly state what term you want help defining.

Comment: KonKan: if $C$ express abelian group and $F(C)$ hasn't the commutative property then structure changed. hardmath: i read from different sources the definition. the definition of concrete category has necessary faithful functor but not necessary forgetful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A concrete category is a category equipped with a faithful functor into $Set$. This usually can be thought of as a forgetful functor, since in cases like $Ab$ and $Ring$, the faithful functor $F$ just forgets the abelian group/ring structure. But the actual definition of a concrete category only involves the idea of a faithful functor.